# Ionic 4 - Lambda - Cors error: missing token ‘audience’ in CORS header

Tags: angular, ionic4

I've got an ionic app running on my pc, (localhost), accessing routes from my Lambda application. When I try a route, I get this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at /dev/login. (Reason: missing token ‘audience’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

Is this coming from the localhost, or the url I'm trying running the route from?  And how do I fix this?

I can access the root url route in a browser fine with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following explanation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowHeaderFromPreflight

Basically you define on server-side a list of 'allowed' headers (Access-Control-Allow-Headers), in your case, the header 'audience' is not allowed. So to fix it you'd need to edit the list and add it on the server-side.

I might be wrong, but I strongly believe you don't need this header. I guess what is happening is that you're getting the JWT token but then instead of just using the header 'Authorization' with value 'Bearer XYZ', where XYZ - your token, you added 'audience' as well (which I believe is also coming from JWT response). If this is correct, using 'Authorization' is sufficient.

An example of JWT and Ionic: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-jwt-login/